# Django admin: add widget link broken

Tags: python, django-admin

Not sure how I did this and have searched everywhere for a solution, but can not find one.  I have managed to either install incorrectly or break my installation of a default Django 1.3.1 admin project so that the **add** widget is rendered with a broken link.

[image: default auth user properties page's add widget]

The above link should be rendered as `http://mynode.com/admin/auth/group/add/`, but is being rendered as `http://mynode.com/$auth/group/add/` instead.  This is consistent on every page were the **add** widget is displayed.  Any ideas what I have broken or what is missing from my settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, very interesting...  found it and feeling foolish now.

I put some prints throughout the Django admin and core code and discovered that my problem was coming from within the call...

```
`related_url = reverse('admin:%s_%s_add' % info, current_app=self.admin_site.name)`
```

found inside django/contrib/admin/widgets.py.  `reverse()` in an effort to craft the URL for my projects link, iterates through the `resolver.namespace_dict` looking for something that will match the namespace or current app, in this case *admin*.  A quick check in my `url.py` file found the following entry...

```
( r'^$', include(admin.site.urls) ),
```

I guess I had added this entry in an attempt to do something (which I've completely forgotten...  Dooh!) and this caused `reverse()` to render my widgets link incorrectly.    :(

**Update**
I remember now.  I was trying to add a root site handler.  `mysite.com/`  This works but the trick is to make sure this entry is after

```
`( r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),`
```

in your urlpatterns.